# Google Cloud Storage file upload error in Google App Engine standard running PHP 7

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blueimp

I have a PHP 7 app built using the Google App Engine standard environment, and I want to be able to upload files and store them in Google Cloud Storage.  I am using the `Blueimp jQuery File Upload` plugin to handle the uploading of files.

I am getting a number of errors.  There is an error message saying `failed to open stream: Read-only file system`.  These are the error messages:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/srv/c/server/php/files/cats.png): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 1152

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpsKIIYL' to '/srv/c/server/php/files/cats.png' in /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 1152

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /srv/c/server/php/files/cats.png in /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 322

Warning: unlink(/srv/c/server/php/files/cats.png): Read-only file system in /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 1171

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php:1152) in /srv/c/server/php/UploadHandler.php on line 1201

{"files":[{"name":"cats.png","size":false,"type":"image\/png","error":"File upload aborted","deleteUrl":"https:\/\/myproject.appspot.com\/c\/server\/php\/index.php?file=cats.png","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of logic are you using to save the files to GCS?

Comment: You need to post your code

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code to upload an object to your bucket php:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

//create a bucket 
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('my_bucket');


//upload file
$source = 'path_to_file'
$file = fopen($source, 'r');
$objectName = 'my_file'
$object = $bucket->upload($file, [
    'name' => $objectName
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Marian, but I already have a bucket so don't need to create a new one.